# What is the most possible memory consumed by mobile game while game is still running smoothly?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, memory, programming-languages

I am a new mobile game developer and I am just start to make some games by flash and AS3. While testing the memory used by my game(by tracing System.totalMemoryNumber), I found that my game consumes around 80MB and it's still going to grow. Could you tell me what is the limit that my game still run smoothly on those popular mobiles such as iPhone and Android devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know about Android, but on iPhone you can use all the memory that is available at a certain point. This means that if the total memory is 128 MB (iPhone 3g) and the system takes ~80 MB (this can really be more or less, depends on many things) you have around 40 MB to play with. Now, this is really just for you to make an idea about it could be less or more. There is no hard coded limit, you can use what remains unused by the system.

Answer (score 3):

I got to see Mike Chambers' talk last year which was mostly about optimizing for mobile. The biggest takeaway was the information about how the graphics are rendered.

boils down to this... cache movie clips as bitmaps. use sprite sheets if you can, because the mobile devices can handle displaying bitmap better than having to rasterize EVERY frame.

Adobe even added a transform matrix for bitmap objects, to make this faster 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS901d38e593cd1bac-11f566412b2b29517b-8000.html

give this a read if you get a chance
http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/files/presentations/fitc_amsterdam_2010/flash_iphone_fitc_2010.pdf

and check out the source code for 'pew pew' at http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2010/07/14/source-code-for-pewpew-released/

hope this helps

Comment: in retrospect, that's more of an issue with framerate/performance than memory usage, but the talk slides might have some good info for you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really difficult question to answer because every device has a different amount of memory.  Bottom line is that there is no predefined limit or magic number.

Your best bet is to check out the performance with Device Central using the "Device Performance Panel".  Try testing you game with it across a few different platforms and see how it performs.

...or you could always buy a few different phones and try running the game on it :P

Comment: I like the last sentence ~:D I wish I could. I also think of the device central but will it work as the phone memory property or as my PCs?

Comment: Check out this from adobe about using the Device Performance Panel http://help.adobe.com/en_US/devicecentral/cs/using/WS41C18A1E-420A-4b43-ADCE-33FBC91BFFABa.html